# About ASIHTTPRequest send request

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest `[request startAsynchronous]` functon to send a request to my webservice api to login. If the request is ok, it returns a json value. Then I send another request to get user's info, but here I receive an error.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)login
{
    [usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];

    username = [usernameTextField text];
    password = [passwordTextField text];

    if ( ([username length] == 0 ) || ([password length] == 0 )) 
    {
       ...
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/Login?user=%@&pass=%@",username,password];
        NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
        [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) 
    {
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
        NSString *unlockCode = [responseDict objectForKey:@"d"];
        if ( [unlockCode isEqualToString:@"successful"] ) 
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetUserInfo?user=%@",username];
            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
            [request startSynchronous];**//THERE IS AN ERROR**
            NSError *error = [request error];
            if (!error) 
            {
                NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
                NSString *realName = [responseDict objectForKey:@"RealName"];
                NSLog(@"%@",realName);
            } 
        }
        else
        {
           //...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }
}
```

And there is an error:

> [__NSCFString absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x69ef4b0

Another error:

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate
>   (_selectionLayoutChangedByScrolling:) failed to return after waiting
>   10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Comment: There is an incorrect initialization of the NSURL. It should be like this NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"YOUR URL"]];

Comment: Yeap,such a stupid mistake! Thank you for your help, have a good day!!!

Comment: It happens :) Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetUserInfo?user=%@",username];
```

It should be changed to:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetUserInfo?user=%@",username]];
```